# Does changing minsdk version affects our laptop?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Does changing minsdk version in vs code affects our laptop
Why we have to change minsdk version ?

Comment: Of course it will affect your laptop. Generally when you give some instruction or configuration to software on a machine, it affects how that software behaves on that machine. What exactly are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the minSdkVersion in a Flutter project doesn't affect your laptop; it affects the Android application you are developing. The minSdkVersion specifies the minimum API level required for the Android device to run the application.

If you set the minSdkVersion to a higher level, it means that your app will only run on devices that are running that version of Android or higher. This could allow you to use newer Android features but might also mean that your app can't be installed on older devices.

On the other hand, setting a lower minSdkVersion means that your app can run on a wider range of devices, including older ones, but you may not be able to utilize some of the newer Android features.

In either case, this setting won't have any direct impact on your laptop or development environment. It is related to the target devices for your application.

Answer (score 1):

It does not affect your computer in any way. min Sdk Version is the version you use to avoid problems when using 3rd party applications in your project.

Some packages may request your minSdkVersion at the current level. That's why it needs to be changed. I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.